# Why isn't this method rendering my .js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this method in my videos controller:

```
def notification_go
  current_user.render_read
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render 'notification_go.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

It is not rendering my `notification_go.js.erb` file in my `videos` view directory. Why is this? How do I render it?

(My `notification_go` method is called via an AJAX request. Not sure if that makes any difference.)

Comment: Did you try `render 'notification_go'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing

```
:format => :js
```

to path in your AJAX request.

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to specify render 'notification_go.js.erb' by default its already been mapped, the filename of notification_go.js.erb template with controller action notication_go

```
def notification_go
  current_user.render_read
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```