# Render partial containing javascript from a js.erb file

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial

I have a `.js.erb` file that renders a partial like so:

```
$("#tasks").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "task_from_app") %>");
```

I now need to put some javascript inside `task_from_app`, but the javascript doesn't work.

Removing `escape_javascript` doesn't work either - no error is shown and the partial isn't rendered on the page.

How can I get the partial to render if it includes javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tasks").append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "task_from_app").html_safe %>");
```

Comment: The javascript doesn't render with your version.

Comment: It works for me, have you tried `single quotes` like `.append('<%= %>')`

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working for me. I'm seeing the partial render just fine, but the javascript is missing.

Comment: Is there any way to append these partials and have the javascript run? I don't really want to escape the javascript if this means it wont actually execute.

Comment: Ref:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933747/why-isnt-this-method-rendering-my-js-erb-file

Comment: I'll try rendering a `.js.erb` instead of a `.html.erb`. Thing is, it strikes me I'll have the same problem if I use an `erb` statement to try to render a separate partial that contains javascript.